# Eager Loading on existing Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In rails you can eager load associations when you create a new object like this:

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id], :include => {:flights => :plane})
```

However, i sometimes already have the @person object and then want to eager load the associations. There does not seem to be any 'rails' way to do this. I am looking for something like this basically:

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
...
@person.include({:flights => :plane})
```

Background is, I have a before filter that already creates the @object without associations. But in some actions if i do not eager load the associations i will generate a lot of singular queries. And doing

```
@person = Person.find(params[:id])
...
@person = Person.find(params[:id], :include => {:flights => :plane})
```

seems like a bit of a waste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Rails 2, you can use `scoped` to create the appropriate query:

```
 @person.flights.scoped(:include => :plane)
```

In Rails 3, you can do this the Rails 3 Way:

```
 @person.flights.include(:plane)
```

You might consider adding the `:include` option to your `has_many` declaration so it is included by default when loaded from Person:

```
 has_many :flights, :include => :plane
```

You can alternately add a default scope to Flight, causing any query on Flight to include its plane:

```
 default_scope :include => :plane
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@person.flights` and set a `default_scope` on flights to include plane.
Or in your Person model: `has_many :flights, :include => plane`

You should switch to Rails3, check out [Active Record Queries in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3) to see why!